# Laravel How to remove "api" Prefix from subdomain URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-routing

I have created a Laravel application which is both Web application and  provides REST APIs to android and iOS platforms.

I have two route files one is api.php and other is web.php and routes\api.php routing as follows:

```
routes/api.php
    Route::group([
    'domain'=>'api.example.com',
    function(){
        // Some routes ....
    }
);
```

and nginx serve blocks configured can be seen here

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/laravel/public;
index index.php;
server_name api.example.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

}

I was be able to access my application using `http://example.com` for web application and  `http://api.example.com/api/cities` for REST API's. But the subdomain URL contains **api** as prefix as given below.

```
http://api.example.com/api/cities
```

But i want to my subdomain like this `http://api.example.com/cities` (I wanted to `remove` api prefix from the sub domain URL).

Is it right way to remove prefix **api** in `RouteServiceProvide.php` for api routes?

Or is they any right way to implement this?

Environment Details
Laravel 5.5 (LTS)
PHP 7.0

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It's just prefix to differ your api routes from other routes. You can add something different from `api` to here.

In `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` change this function:

```
   /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
```

Remove prefixe line:

```
   /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, Is it right way to do the above things ?

Comment: Yeah it is right way. I think default api routes is not created for subdomains. Because of they added api prefix to differ api routes from your web or admin routes.

Comment: If i have removed api prefix in RoutesServiceProvider, will it gets collide with web.php routes ?

Comment: No I don't think this will happens. But try to don't give names to api routes that looks like web.php routes.

Comment: Will [Laravel sub-domain routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing) helps in this scenario ?

Comment: @lakshmaji it is optional. You can use both sub-domain routing and normal routing for you api. You can use web.php to your routes too. Only difference is the url of your api.

Comment: Thank for you help. and one final question, if I have used subdomain prefix in routes file, do I need to add any additional configurations ?

Comment: No. You only need to configure sub-domain name (which I see that you already configured it in above) in routes. You can read additional information about sub-domain routing [in official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing)

Comment: Thank you very much for help

Comment: I will go with RouteServiceProviders :D

Comment: What if we want to use sub-domain (admin.example.com)  instead of example.com/admin in the above scenario. (i.e, without removing router prefix)

Answer (score 8):

Actually in Laravel 8, i just remove api from prefix in App/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

```
Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

to

```
Route::prefix('/')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

Answer (score 4):

also remember to whitelist your whole app for CORS check in the config/cors.php file if u want the whole app to be an api with "/api" prefix removed

in config/cors.php

```
 'paths' => ['*'],
```